# Macro expansion order confusion between compilers

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, macros, clang

This piece of code compiles in Visual Studio 2015, but not in Clang:

```
#define COMMA ,
#define MC(a) a
#define MA(a,b,c) MC(a b c)
map <MA(int,COMMA,int)> FF;
```

It appears that Clang expands the *COMMA* macro before submitting it to the MC() macro. "Who is right" according to the C++ standard? Also, how can I make Clang behave like Visual Studio?

EDIT: Simplified the example, and changed some macro names.

Comment: Pedantically `_COMMA` is reserved so the behaviour of all this is undefined. That's *unlikely* to be the problem though.

Comment: Thanks (corrected the question), but indeed, this makes no difference.

Comment: It's still UB .

Comment: @Bathsheba Perhaps you should explain [*why* it is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/a/228797/1171191).

Comment: Considering that [MS documents their preprocessor support as partial](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/05/10/c17-features-in-vs-2017-3/) even for the next release, I would put my money on clang.

Answer (score 0):

Clang conforms to the standard; Visual Studio doesn't. I think you will have a lot of trouble getting Clang to not conform to the standard, so I won't attempt to answer "how do I get Clang to act like Visual Studio?". Maybe that wasn't really what you wanted to know.

When the compiler identifies the invocation of a function-like macro (that is, a macro with parameters) it expands the macro using the procedure explained in detail in §16.3 `[cpp.replace]` of the C++ standard. In the following, I've simplified the procedure by not considering the `#` and `##` operators, because they do not appear in your example and the full procedure is more complicated.

We'll examine the invocation `MC(int, COMMA, int)`. Here's what happens after the compiler sees the tokens `MC` and `(`, which indicate an invocation of the macro.

1. The compiler identifies what the arguments are, which involves finding the closing parenthesis. There are three arguments, which corresponds to the number of parameters, so that's OK. The arguments have not yet been expanded, so the compiler only sees the punctuation actually in the source file. It identifies the arguments as `int`, `COMMA` and `int`.
2. Every argument (except the ones whose corresponding parameter participates in token concatenation or stringification -- but, as I said, I'm not going to go into that scenario here) are then fully expanded. This happens before they are substituted into the macro body, so that the names of the macro's parameters don't leak out of the macro. So now the three arguments are `int`, `,` and `int`.
3. A copy of the macro body is made, in which each parameter is substituted with the corresponding (fully expanded) argument. The macro body ("replacement list", in standardese) was `MC(A B C)`; after substituting the arguments, that becomes `MC(A , C)`.
4. The sequence of tokens created in step 3 is inserted into the input in place of the macro invocation, and preprocessing continues.

At this point, the compiler will see the invocation of the function-like macro `MC(A, B)`, and will proceed as above. However, this time the first step fails because two arguments are identified but the macro `MC` only has one parameter.